# finding common key in array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, filtering

```
let array = [
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", fr: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", gu: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", hi: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", la: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "" },
    ];
```

I have this array of objects and want to find the common key from all objects

the final output should be like

`let array2 =[ "en", "ar", "sp"]`

so the filter should only return the key's which are available in every objects. I am not able to find the best algorithm for this sorting. A little guidance will also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [
{ en: "", ar: "", sp: "", fr: "" },
{ en: "", ar: "", sp: "", gu: "" },
{ en: "", ar: "", sp: "", hi: "" },
{ en: "", ar: "", sp: "", la: "" },
{ en: "", ar: "", sp: "" }]

const allKeys = [...new Set(array.flatMap(i=>Object.keys(i)))]

const commonKeys = allKeys.filter(i=>!array.some(j=>!Object.keys(j).includes(i)))

console.log(commonKeys)
```

Comment: Thanks @andrew parks. I am so worried about my logic how to improve my knowledge if you can share any links it will be so helpful.

Comment: @dhruvinvaghasiya don't worry, all of this was incredibly confusing to me when I first started to learn it, because I kept having to look things up. But after you've practised using it enough when programming, what was once hard to remember then becomes second nature. Just keep programming things, and bit by bit you'll pick things up.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", fr: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", gu: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", hi: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", la: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "" },
];

let keysArr = array.map(x => Object.keys(x));

let commonKeys = keysArr.pop().reduce((res, x) => {
  const isEvery = keysArr.every((i) => i.includes(x));
  if (!res.includes(x) && isEvery) {
    res.push(x);
  }

  return res;
}, []);

console.log(commonKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to do with reduce, Object.keys, filter, and includes.

First pass in reduce you just store the keys of the object.

Each pass after that you are just looking for the keys that exist in the current row.

```js
let array = [
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", fr: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", gu: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", hi: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "", la: "" },
    { en: "", ar: "", sp: "" },
];

const commonKeys = array.reduce((commonKeys, item, index) => {
  // get the keys
  const itemKeys = Object.keys(item);
  // if we are at first index, return the keys
  // If we are > 1, filter only the keys that are in the object
  return !index ? itemKeys : commonKeys.filter(key => itemKeys.includes(key));
}, []);

console.log(commonKeys);
```